# Development Life Cycle for Apache NiFi

Tags: deployment, apache-nifi, lifecycle

I realize that with NiFi, as their doc defines it, *"continuous improvement occurs in production"*. So this doesn’t lend itself to be used as a traditional development tool. However for the project I’m working on it’s been decided that this is the tool we’ll be using, so I'd rather not debate the merits of this as I realize there are going to be some issues.

For example if I push changes into an existing environment (from staging to production) and there were live edits in the destination, they are going to get overwritten. So I have questions on how to organize the development life cycle.

- Is it possible to **merge changes** which were done by multiple developers in parallel (merge exported xml template files)? I’m guessing merging any significant changes could be difficult but have not attempted it.
- How to **manage versioning** changes? I’m assuming you could export your entire configuration as a template and check that into version control?
- How to **deploy a flow** to a different server? Can you just deploy a stock NiFi deployment and then update it from your exported template (as mentioned above) using the NiFi REST API?
- How to mange deploying to different environment that might have **different configuration**? Would you have to update the template XML file? Or can I pull it in dynamically from something like Zookeeper?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the original author of the item you quoted and a member of the Apache NiFi PMC let me start by saying you're asking great questions and I can appreciate where you're coming from.  We should probably improve the introduction document to better reflect the concerns you're raising.

You have it right that the current approach is to create templates of the flows and then you can submit that to version control.  It is also the case that folks automate the deployment of these templates using scripts interacting with NiFi's REST API.  But we can and should do far more than we have to make the dataflow management job easier regardless of whether you're a developer writing precisely what will be deployed or whether you're an operations focused person having to put these pieces together yourself.

1. Management and versioning of flows [1] should be easier and centrally managed to be shared across multiple clusters and environments [2].
2. We need to make sure that environment specific values are easily mapped into a given environment but that the templates are still portable [3].
3. We need to make the multi-user/multi-tenant user experience far more intuitive and natural [4].

Elements of 1 and 2 will be present in the upcoming 1.0 release and item 3 is totally covered in that upcoming release.  In the mean time for the multi-developer case I think it makes sense for them to treat their own local instance as a place for 'unit testing' their flow and then using a shared staging or production environment.  The key thing to keep in mind is that for many flows and with NiFi's approach it is ok to have multiple instances of a given flow template executing each being fed the live feed of data.  The results/output of that flow can be wired to actually get delivered somewhere or simply be grounded.  In this way it is a lot like the mental model of branching in source control such as Git.  You get to choose which one you consider 'production' versus which flow on the graph is simply an ongoing feature branch if you will.  For people coming from the more traditional approach this is not obvious and we need to do more to describe and demonstrate this.  However, we should also support more traditional approaches as well and that is what some of the feature proposals I've linked to will enable.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Configuration+Management+of+Flows

[2] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Extension+Registry

[3] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Variable+Registry

[4] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Multi-Tentant+Dataflow

Comment: It looks like [1], [2] and [3] are not implemented yet. Can you give an update on how you would solve the stated problems in the current release version? I think right now people are just importing and exporting templates. That has some drawbacks, e.g. no real update option, you can just remove the old version and readd the new one.

Comment: You're right there is no true update option (for an existing process group).  The common pattern today is to push a new version of the process group then change the connections that feed that group.  This can be done with a couple REST calls programmatically.  The apache nifi registry for flow management, process group variables, and versioned components are all well underway with the latter two in the latest release The next release looks likely to have the apache nifi registry integrated for versioned flows and at that point you'll get the true update!  Should be very cool.

Comment: I have a issue related to deployment in team development. We have 2 NiFi env ( STA, PROD) we have multiple versioned PGs. 
I’d like to ask you about the best practice during working with multiple NiFi developers. We would like to avoid situation to push STA– > PRO when someone finish work on one task while other member still working on different task in same versioned PG. So when I push it to PRO we will have inconsistent state of NiFi workflow. We are wondering how to avoid such situation. 
Does Nifi Registry has something like “branch” in git?
Thanks in advance